# Which is the best way to log user actions in flask views?

Tags: python, flask, flask-sqlalchemy

I would like to log user actions whenever user logs in/out and adds, edits, deletes objects in my site models in flask. Which is the best way to do this? Also I would like to show the old data and the new modified data, which happens using wtfforms. I am using flask and Flask-SQLAlchemy. I want something similar to what Django framework offers in the '**History**' hlink for the associated objects.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use Signals. Take a look at this

http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/signals/

Using signals, you can keep track of any actions such as adds/edits etc. as needed. All you have to do is

```
from blinker import Namespace
my_signals = Namespace()

def add_user():
    # add user code here
    user_added = my_signals.signal('user-added')
```

Comment: Sorry for delay. Again it is not different from adding a small function with parameters to be called in the different views. What is the advantage of using these signals over the function call using session variables? Can you please show a short code sample for adding an object in a model using signal in a flask view except the one mentioned in the docs.

Answer (score 2):

You can refer to [flask-login](https://flask-login.readthedocs.org/en/latest/), also using Signals.